# Delete column and row of 2d Array after every iteration

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

wihin an project i need to calculate max value for a given score. Afterwards this particular row and related column should be deleted in order to get just one max value in every row. So my result should look like this:

Result

[image]

This is what i have so far.

```
    float max = Float.MIN_VALUE;
    int remove_row = firstCluster.size()+1;
    int remove_column = firstCluster.size()+1;
    float[ ][ ] scores = new float[firstCluster.size()][secondCluster.size()];

    for(int i=0; i<scores.length; i++){
       if ( i == remove_row)
            continue;

        for(int j=0; j<scores[i].length; j++){
            if ( j == remove_column){
                continue;
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(scores[i][j]);
                if(scores[i][j] >= max)
                {
                    max = Math.max(max, scores[i][j]);
                    remove_row = i;
                    remove_column = j;
                    System.out.print("Max: "+max);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("##############################");
    }
```

The idea is to skip column and row of previous max value but if you are in 3 iteration then you just skip the column and row of previous one and not of all previous iterations. Is there any better way to solve this? I don't need to use necessary 2d array

Comment: If all the values are positive, just set the values of the "deleted" row or column to zero, so they will not affect the next iterations.

Comment: I agree with @TDG - loop the original 2d array, don't built a new one after each iteration. Instead of putting zeroes in the cells, maintain two Set's - `usedRows` and `usedColumns` - that keeps tracked of the rows and columns you've crossed out, and ship those using an extra if statement just before `if(scores[i][j] >= max)`

Comment: Nice to explain the problem with the easy-to-understan image, btw!

Comment: @Stefan your solution ist realy good the rows and columns are shipped appropiate. I have only issue if in the last iteration zero is only left value. In this case the last max value would not be calculated

Comment: Do you do `max = Float.MIN_VALUE` in the beginning of each iteration? If you do, I don't see why cells full of zeroes should behave any different than cells with values >0.

Comment: No, i am actually initialising max before first for loop starts. If i understand you right, you would do `max = Float.MIN_VALUE` for each row?

Comment: @Stefan Thnx! It works like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just summing up the comments to build a proper answer:

Instead of putting zeroes in the cells, maintain two Set's - `usedRows` and `usedColumns` - that keeps tracked of the rows and columns you've crossed out, and ship those using an extra if statement just before `if(scores[i][j] >= max)`

Remember to reset max in the beginning of each iteraton:

```
max = Float.MIN_VALUE
```